This is not my account- everything is messed up- could a moderator please help
I am security_paranoid
security_paranoid is my only account. My name is Harvey.
But let me catch you up to speed.
A few days ago, I contacted StackExchange through their help centre, because I was having a problem with updating the "about me" account info.
Whenever I finish using Security SE, I sign out of my account.
But when I signed back in a few hours ago, I got a nasty surprise.
My profile change was the first thing I realized, but then I realized everything had been merged with another account. My username has changed to Hman66, and some of this user's questions are now on my account. Other logins have also been added, and some of them are emails with the name harvey, like mine, but with a different last name. This really surprised me.
I checked my emails and StackExchange notified me that they merged accounts, but without context. I have emailed them back and I am currently waiting a reply.
I only have one account- security_paranoid. I made this account a few months ago and have used the same email, harvey.infosec@gmail.com, and I used this email when I signed up, and haven't changed it. Although, I never check my account info, so it's possible that it automatically got changed.
I am kinda stressed out because I don't know who this other Harvey is, but it sure ain't me!
I don't care what the 'systems' say- I have one account, with one email- only.
Could a moderator please help.

@schroeder do you know what has happened? Do you know a user called "Hman66"? I am really confused.

Nothing mods can do. You need to contact user support again.

@schroeder thanks and yeah I will. I understand- thanks anyway. But is this a user or something? I tried searching but couldn’t find anyone called this… maybe the accounts got merged because both of our names are harvey?

Yes, there is a user with that name.

@schroeder yeah thanks for letting me know and for you time, personally. As it turns out, most of that users answers (that are now mine) have been deleted… by you!! Thanks again for your time :D
